Include ckeditor (configured with the builder) without a preprocessor
I have used the ckeditor builder to configure a custom ckeditor. After I downloaded the files, I found out that the editor cannot be easily integrated into a website.
In the example js file, i found:
import {
...
} from 'ckeditor5';
As far as I know, the "import" requires some javascript preprocessor, but I am not very confident with them.
Is there a way I can include the ckeditor without a javascript preprocessor?
I tried to include the ckeditor, but this was not working as it seems to require a javascript preprocessor.
